# Code equivalent of android:cropToPadding

Tags: android, imageview

In my android app, I create thumbnails in xml this way:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/my_thumbnail
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:padding="2dp"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:cropToPadding="true" />
```

This creates a white border around the thumbnail - and looks quite nice.

Now, in another place in the code I need to create the thumbnails in the code, not XML (this is an Adapter class for GridView - to create a grid of thumbnails).  I can set all parameters as required, however I cannot find a way to set the `cropToPadding` in the code.  As a result, the thumbnail are drawn over the padding and it looks really ugly.

How do I set this `cropToPadding` thing in the code?

BTW, the app must work on Android 1.6.

**Edit**

Following a suggestion from *userSeven7s*, I add this style to my XML containing other styles:

```
<style name="GridImage">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:cropToPadding">true</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

(Note that the file contains `<resources>` root element and contains a couple of other `<style>` elements.  Yet all of the other ones are only referenced form layout xml files.)

I then added this code inside my grid view adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        XmlPullParser parser = mContext.getResources().getXml(R.style.GridImage);
        AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext, attributes);
        // ... some more initialisation
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    // ... code to create the bitmap and set it into the ImageView goes here
}
```

This compiles fine (i.e. `R.style.GridImage` exists).  However when I run this code, the app crashes with `Resources.NotFoundException` on `getXml(R.style.GridImage)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: show some code where you create the imageviews.  You have added the code that works, when it should be the code that doesn't work..

Comment: I can't show the code - because I can't find the corresponding code.  In the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html code equivalent is shown for all XML elements except `android:cropToPadding`.  Does this mean there is no equivalent?

Comment: Yes seems there is no equivalent method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the thumbnails from the `ImageView` itself. Call `getDrawingCache()` on each imageview to get the bitmap used for drawing.

### new Update :

Create a xml `myimage_attrs.xml` in `xml` folder and add all the `imageview` attributes you need to it.

```
<?xml version=”1.0″ encoding=”utf-8″?>
<item name=”android:layout_height”>10dp</item>
<item name=”android:layout_width”>10dp</item>
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
<item name="android:cropToPadding">true</item>
<item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
....
```

Then create a `AttributeSet` out of the xml and pass it to the `ImageView` constructor.

```
XmlPullParser parser = resources.getXml(R.xml.myimage_attrs);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

ImageView imgv = new ImageView(context, attributes);
```

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with my question.  I'm not asking how to get the thumbnails.  I need to know how to get ImageView to `cropToPadding` in the code.

Comment: @useSeven7s: no, `setPadding()` is the equivalent of `android:padding` in XML; `android:cropToPadding` is something completely different.

Comment: Just got around to trying this - and got error `Resources$NotFoundException` on line `XMLPullParser parser = mContext.getResources().getXml(R.style.GridImage);` Any ideas?

Comment: This didn't work exactly as you described, as it's missing a few things. However I did manage to finally get this to work. For the benefit of others who may be viewing this question, I'll post the full solution into a separate answer - and will still accept your answer as it got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you try the solution with `AttributeSet` and `attributes.getAttributeCount()` always returns `0`, then just about the only solution left is this hack using reflection:

```
Field field = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mCropToPadding");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(imageView, true);
```

Using this you probably can't be sure it will work in other android firmware versions.
Anyway the missing setter is probably just forgotten, so that justifies the hack for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, here's what finally did work (thanks to *userSeven7s* for pushing me in the right direction).

I created `grid_image.xml` file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:cropToPadding">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
</style>
```

Then in my Adapter for the grid view, I put the following code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        XmlPullParser parser = mContext.getResources().getXml(R.xml.grid_image);
        AttributeSet attributes = null;
        int state = XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT;
        do {
            try {
                state = parser.next();
                if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getName().equals("style")) {
                        attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            //ignore it - can't do much anyway
        } while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);

        if(attributes == null)
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        else
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext, attributes);

        //the rest of initialisation goes here
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    //set image into the imageview here

    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this xml file was valid on an older android-sdk api. For me I had to create an xml with a regular imageview tag inside, in order for the parser to work properly: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="190dp"
      android:layout_height="190dp"
      android:contentDescription="pet photo"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:src="@drawable/dummy_not_found_card"/>`